# How do I get a Refresh_Token from a ADFS 3.0 end point in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jwt, adfs3.0

I have been securing a webapi using Rob Sander's instructions, found here: [Securing a web api with adfs 3.0 and jwt tokens](http://sanderstechnology.com/2015/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-3-0-and-jwt-tokens/14297/#.WTkZDGiGM2w)

I have successfully performed a login via ADFS using the usernamemixed end point, and have received the encoded Json Web Token (JWT). That's fine, and I can successfully validate the token with the X509 certificate found in the federation data xml found on the ADFS server.

I have implemented a DelegatingHandler so that any Authorize attributes added to methods will be checked.

The final piece of the puzzle is where I can get the refresh_token from. It would make sense to come from an ADFS endpoint, and I thought it would be in the response from the usernamemixed end point, but it doesn't appear to be there. Also, how do I make a call to request a new access_token if I provide a refresh_token?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, there's another OAuth endpoint. You would have /authorize, /token and /refresh.

Not sure in ADFS 3.0 implements this?

You can get it via:

Set-AdfsRelyingPartyTrust -TargetName "RPT Name" -IssueOAuthRefreshTokensTo AllDevices

More details [here](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/09/OAUTH2-Authentication-with-ADFS-3.0.html).

Comment: I did enable OAuth Refresh Tokens but the jwt returned still doesn't contain the Refresh Token. Some of the other setting changes I made, like token lifetime, were reflected in the jwt.

Comment: I am using the usernamemixed endpoint. It is only giving me an access_token. If I had another way to obtain the token that still allowed authentication with a user name and password and gave me back the access_token and refresh_token then I would be happy with that. That said, I would also need to know how to call the Refresh Token method. I have had a look at ADAL but that seems to pop up a window, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: The problem with ADFS 3.0 is that OAuth support is limited. It only supports Auth. Code Grant which is why you get the pop-up window,